# How to provide user options with expanding layouts QVBoxLayout in QT

Tags: c++, qt

I currently have 3 Vertical Layouts in my form. I want to provide the user the option of resizing them to their liking by stretching them. Can this be achieved with Vertical layouts ?

Comment: [QSplitter](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qsplitter.html) might be your friend, but you surely need to enclose your vertical layout in a `QFrame`

Comment: I dont see QSplitter in QT Designer

Comment: For what I see in my version (2.5.2), there is no way to add a `QSplitter` from designer. But C++ and your keyboard sould be able to bridge the gap ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can use QSplitter as said before. Even being not possible to add it by Designer, there is a way to solve. Create those frames in your widget (which have no layout), and in your cpp and h file you will do that:

in header, write

```
class YourClass : public QSplitter
```

instead

```
class YourClass : public QWidget
```

and replace in your cpp these declaration on constructor

```
QWidget(parent)
```

for

```
QSplitter(parent)
```

I guess it does (or almost, perhaps some other changes will be necessary, as add include files).

EDIT: at this time usin code in a QMainWindow class:

```
QSpliter *splitter = new QSplitter(this) //or declare 'splitter' in .h file.
splitter->setOrientation(Qt::Vertical);
splitter->addWidget(widget1); 
splitter->addWidget(widget2);
splitter->addWidget(widget3);

setCentralWidget(splitter);
```

Comment: Is it the same case if your form inherits from QMainWindow ?

Comment: No, i guess. I always did that using QWidget forms, because 'setupUi' takes as argument a QMainWindow* object (and we just turn it into QSpliter).

Comment: Using QWidget form, you can use your QSplitter as argument to 'setupUi', and have no problem with that.

Answer (score 0):

As of 4.8.6, it's possible to add a QSplitter in Qt Designer by using the *Lay out [horizontally/vertically] in splitter* layout option. It's somewhat surprising that it's not listed in the widget box, but you can use it.